# How do I rollback a SQL CLR stored procedure when a user cancels the query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I'm trying to create a SQL CLR stored procedure that will create a table, pass the table name onto a service which will bulk insert some data into it, display the results of the table, then clean up the table.

What I've tried so far:

1. Use `SqlTransaction`. Cancelling the transaction works, but it puts my query window into a state where I couldn't continue working on it.

   > The transaction active in this session has been committed or aborted by another session
2. Use `TransactionScope`. Same issue as 1.
3. Manually clean up the table in a `finally` clause by issuing a `DROP TABLE` `SqlCommand`. This doesn't seem to get run, though my `SqlContext.Pipe.Send()` prior to issuing the command does. It doesn't seem like it's related to any time constraints since if I issue a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` before printing another line, it still prints the second line whereas the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` would stop before printing the second line.
4. Placing the manual cleanup code into a CER or `SafeHandle`. This doesn't work as having a CER requires some guarantees, including not allocating additional memory or calling methods that are not decorated with a `ReliabilityContract`.

Am I missing something obvious here?  How do I handle the user cancelling their query?

Edit: There were multiple iterations of the code for each scenario, but the general actions taken are along the lines of the following:

```
    [SqlProcedure]
    public static void GetData(SqlString code)
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            try
            {
                SqlContext.Pipe?.Send("Constrain");

                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand($"CREATE TABLE qb.{code}_{guid:N} (Id INT)", connection);
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlContext.Pipe?.Send($"Create: qb.{code}_{guid:N}");

                //emulate service call
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

                SqlContext.Pipe?.Send($"Done: qb.{code}_{guid:N}");
            }
            finally
            {
                SqlContext.Pipe?.Send("1");
                //drop table here instead of sleep
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                SqlContext.Pipe?.Send("2");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: add the relevant code parts

Comment: a simplistic answer would be if the user cancels the query then immediately drop the table.  The service first tests if the table is present before doing the work, if not there it assumes user cancelled the query so it does nothing.

Comment: @Rob The problem is getting the table to drop after the user cancels the query.  The `finally` block does not execute `DROP TABLE` as mentioned in attempt 3.

Comment: And where is the part with the query window?

Comment: @SirRufo I did not include it as it is just a single call `EXEC clrproc 'parameter'`

Comment: I take it the service is not/cannot be cancelled by the user, so have the service create the table (just pass the table name) as well as display & cleanup/drop table?

Comment: @Rob If the service drops the table, how is the SQL CLR proc going to select the results of it after the data is populated?  I don't want to return the data set from the service and deal with serialization and contracts of multiple different types of data sets.

Comment: ok, was how you wrote " pass the table name onto a service which will bulk insert some data into it, display the results of the table, then clean up the table." - reads as 'the service is doing all of the work, display and clean-up.'

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately SQLCLR does not handle query cancellation very well. However, given the error message, that seems to imply that the cancellation does its own `ROLLBACK`. Have you tried not using a Transaction within the SQLCLR code but instead handling it from outside? Such as:

1. `BEGIN TRAN;`
2. `EXEC SQLCLR_Stored_Procedure;`
3. `IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRAN;`

The workflow noted above would need to be enforced. This can be done rather easily by creating a wrapper T-SQL Stored Procedure that executes those 3 steps and only give `EXECUTE` permission to the wrapper Stored Procedure. If permissions are then needed for the SQLCLR Stored Procedure, that can be accomplished rather easily using module signing:

1. Create an Asymmetric Key in the same DB as the SQLCLR Stored Procedure
2. Create a User from that Asymmetric Key
3. `GRANT` that Key-based User `EXECUTE` permission on the SQLCLR Stored Procedure
4. Sign the wrapper T-SQL Stored Procedure, using `ADD SIGNATURE`, with that Asymmetric Key

Those 4 steps allow the *T-SQL wrapper proc* to execute the SQLCLR proc, while the actual application Login can only execute the T-SQL wrapper proc :-). And, in, the event that the cancellation aborts the execution prior to executing `ROLLBACK`, the Transaction should be automatically rolled-back when the connection closes.

Also, do you have `XACT_ABORT` set to `ON` or `OFF`? **UPDATE:** O.P. states that it is set to `OFF`, and setting to `ON` did not seem to behave any differently.

Have you tried checking the connection state in the `finally` block? I am pretty sure that the `SqlConnection` is `Closed` upon the cancellation. You could try the following approaches, both in the `finally` block:

1. Test for the connection state and if `Closed`, re-open the `SqlConnection` and then execute the non-query command.

   **UPDATE:** O.P. states that the connection is still open. Ok, how about closing it and re-opening it?

   **UPDATE 2:** O.P. tested and found that the connection could not be re-opened.
2. Since the context is still available, as proven by your print commands working, use something like `SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend(new SqlCommand("DROP TABLE..;"));`

   **UPDATE:** O.P. states that this did not work.

**OR**, since you create a guaranteed unique table name in the code, you can try creating the table as a global temporary table (i.e. prefixed with two pound-signs: `##TableName`) which will a) be available to the bulk import process, and b) clean itself up when the connection fully closes. In this approach, you technically wouldn't need to perform any manual clean up.

Of course, when Connection Pooling is enabled, the automatic cleanup happens only after the connection is re-opened *and* the first command is executed. In order to force an immediate cleanup, you would have to connect to SQL Server with Connection Pooling disabled. Is it possible to use a different Connection String just when this Stored Procedure is to be executed that includes `Pooling=false;`? Given how this Stored Procedure is being used, it does not seem like you would suffer any *noticeable* performance degradation from disabling Connection Pooling on just this one specific call. To better understand how Connection Pooling – enabled or disabled – affects the automatic cleanup of temporary objects, please see the blog post I just published that details this very behavior:

[Sessions, Temporary Objects, and the Afterlife](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/11/20/sessions-temporary-objects-and-the-afterlife/)

This approach is probably the best overall since you probably cannot guarantee either that `ROLLBACK` would be executed (first approach mentioned) or that a finally clause would be executed (assuming you ever got that to work). In the end, uncommitted Transactions will be rolled-back, but if someone executes this via SSMS and it aborts without the `ROLLBACK`, then they are still in an open Transaction and might not be aware of it. Also, think about the connection being forcibly closed, or the Session being killed, or the server being shutdown / restarted. In those cases `tempdb` is your friend, whether by using a global temporary table, or at the very least creating the permanent Table in `tempdb` so that it is automatically removed the next time that the SQL Server starts (due to `tempdb` being created new, as a copy of `model`, upon each start of the SQL Server service).

Comment: 1. Tested that just now and the connection state is actually still open.  2.  Tried this one as well, and it did not execute either.

Comment: My concern with the global temp table is that if someone is working with this proc and cancels it a number of times, it would be keeping all that data within tempdb and using up potentially a large amount of space until they close their tab.  This could lead to performance issues with other unrelated queries as well.

Comment: Ok, interesting, and good to know. Also, if the connection is still open. I wonder if you can close it and re-open it. BUT, hold on, I just thought of two more things. I will update my answer.

Comment: I updated with some additional thoughts and questions. the updates are interspersed so please read the whole thing..

Comment: I can't expect all developers that use this proc to surround it with a transaction.  `XACT_ABORT` is `OFF`, so it shouldn't matter in this case.  Tried to close and reopen the connection, but it wouldn't execute the `connection.Open()`.  I'm going to have to look into connection pooling some more since I'm not familiar with how it works.

Comment: I was just about to update to address the concern of forcing everyone to execute it within an explicit transaction. Can you at least try it to see if it behaves as desired, and if so, I will update with the steps needed to enforce that usage. Also, if you are executing the stored procedure from a .NET app, Connection Pooling is on by default, which is why I suggested adding that keyword to disable it for just the connection that executes this code, but it can be enabled for all other connections. ALSO, can you at least try to see what happens if `XACT_ABORT` is set to `ON`?

Comment: I went ahead and added the steps to enforce that workflow. And if you didn't see my edit to my last comment, I was curious about what would happen if you enabled `XACT_ABORT`.

Comment: I don't think the permission based enforcement would work in our scenario since devs have sysadmin permissions on the dev sql servers.   It also seems that there is in fact a `ROLLBACK` being called somewhere when the cancel query button is pressed.  Tried setting `XACT_ABORT` and it didn't seem to make any functional difference.  Could you explain a bit more on how the cleanup works on `Pooling=false`?  What would trigger a clean up of the table?

Comment: I'm not sure that I would worry so much about the dev environment. If they are "sa", then they can already do A LOT more damage than circumventing your "enforced" workflow here and potentially filling up `tempdb` ;-). Regarding the disabling of Connection Pooling on application connections: by not allowing the connection to remain open (i.e. in the pool, available for another connection request from the same app code), the automatic cleanup happens immediately upon the connection being closed, hence no lingering objects. I will add a link to a blog post I just published on this very topic.

Comment: Silly question: the data that is being bulk inserted into this table by the external service, is that simply being selected for return in a result set, or are you JOINing to other tables, etc with it first? Just wondering why the data is being loaded in the first place, and if it can go directly from external service to the result set and skip the table altogether..

Comment: It could be used in an `INSERT EXEC`.  I'm heavily leaning towards the global temp tables at this point.  Your blog was very helpful in clearing up the differences between the temporary object lifecycles under different conditions.

Comment: What do you mean by "_It could be used in an `INSERT EXEC`_"? Do you mean the output of the SQLCLR stored proc? Or using that table within the SQLCLR stored proc via another SqlCommand / additional logic not shown?

Comment: As in `INSERT INTO #TableWithSameSchema EXEC clrproc`

Comment: So, just to confirm, the external service loads the data into the table created within this SQLCLR stored procedure, and then the data in that table is simply selected out, with nothing else done related to any other objects in the Database?

Comment: At the moment, that seems like a reasonable assumption, though that may not stay the case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160536/discussion-between-solomon-rutzky-and-lunyx).

Answer (score 1):

Stepping back there are probably much better ways to pass the data out of your CLR procedure.

1) you can simply use the SqlContext Pipe to return a resultset without creating a table.

2) you can create a temp table (#) in the calling code and access it from inside the CLR procedure.  You might want to introduce a TSQL wrapper procedure to make this convenient.

Anyway using BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT | ROLLBACK worked for me:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Threading;

static class SqlConnectionExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(this SqlConnection con, string sql, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        foreach (var p in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
        }
        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            return dt;
        }
    }

    public static int ExecuteNonQuery(this SqlConnection con, string sql, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        foreach (var p in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
        }
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void GetData(SqlString code)
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            try
            {
                connection.ExecuteNonQuery("begin transaction;");
                SqlContext.Pipe?.Send("Constrain");

                connection.ExecuteNonQuery($"CREATE TABLE qb.{code}_{guid:N} (Id INT)");

                SqlContext.Pipe?.Send($"Create: qb.{code}_{guid:N}");

                //emulate service call
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

                SqlContext.Pipe?.Send($"Done: qb.{code}_{guid:N}");
                connection.ExecuteNonQuery("commit transaction");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                connection.ExecuteNonQuery("rollback;");
                throw;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: #1 won't work due to the specific workflow of the external service needing to  load data into that table first. #2 won't work due to the data being loaded by another Session. That is why I suggested using a global temp table instead. #3 would be interesting if the `catch` block still had the open connection whereas the `finally` block does not seem to. Though I still prefer to not even rely upon that manual cleanup when a global temp table will be automatically cleaned up no matter what happens.

Comment: "external service needing to load data into that table first" The CLR proc could load a temp table and then pipe the contents to the client. "the data being loaded by another Session" the "context connection" is _not_ a different session.  It's just an API that allows CLR code to access the session that invoked the CLR stored procedure.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of what the Context Connection is. The very beginning of the question states: "_pass the table name onto a service which will bulk insert some data into it_". You even copied the C# comment of `//emulate service call` in your code here. _That_ would be a different Session.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The connection that the service will have is not going to be a context connection and as far as I'm aware, there's no way to pass this connection from SQL CLR to the service.  I am aware that you could return the results without creating a table, but that would put my business logic within the SQL CLR function and I do not want that.

Comment: @Lunyx Correct, the service will not have access to the Context Connection. And David, this is why he is passing the table name to the service, because it makes its own connection to load the data.

Comment: Ahh, got it.  In that case you can't use transactions at all, since the external service wouldn't be able to see a table created in an uncommitted transaction.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft That's actually a good point that I hadn't considered.  Though, in this time, I did get your example working.  I'm curious why the Transaction API behaves differently than calling the commands directly.  I suppose it's doing something entirely different behind the scenes.

Comment: @Lunyx A `SqlTransaction` is managed in .NET and will be automatically rolled-back upon there being an exception. Executing a `SqlCommand` with `BEGIN TRAN;` is unknown to .NET and the Transaction will remain open if there is an exception thrown. Either way, I did confirm that you cannot `INSERT INTO` nor even `SELECT WITH (NOLOCK)` even a global temp table while the transaction in which it was created is still open.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not something advised for use, this would be an ideal match for [`sp_bindsession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-bindsession-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). With `sp_bindsession`, you would call `sp_getbindtoken` from the context session, pass the token to the server and call `sp_bindsession` from the service connection.

Afterwards, the two connections behave "as one", with temporaries and transactions being transparently propagated.